# How do I call a webservice in the Application_Exit event?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

How do I call a webservice in the Application_Exit event?

```
private void Application_Exit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  TestWSSoapClient.ReleaseUserCompleted += new EventHandler<System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs>(TestWSSoapClient_ReleaseUserCompleted);
  TestWSSoapClient.ReleaseUserAsync(UserToken);
}
```

The method below is no longer executed.

```
void TestWSSoapClient_ReleaseUserCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's too late to call an Async service and expect a result by the time you get to Application_Exit. What are you trying to solve? Most workarounds that try to do something on Silverlight shut-down do it via JScript in the hosting page instead.

Comment: Duplicate question of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010064/how-to-call-a-service-when-a-silverlight-oob-app-is-closing-an/4010340#4010340

Answer (score 1):

You can't call any web services when exiting by design, however [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43157/Calling-Web-Services-from-Silverlight-after-the-Br.aspx) might help you with an Javascript alternative.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion.i use JavaScript to call web services.it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to get the response? You won't be able to get it as all threads will be closed at the end of the Application_Exit function. But if it doesn't matter, you can configure your "ReleaseUser" operation as OneWay.

As I didn't test it, it is only a supposition, but I think it should work (and if it doesn't, well, I will learn something)

Otherwise, as said before, javascript is the only way to go, but it won't work Out of Browser.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion.i use JavaScript to call web services.it's working fine.